# uwsgi, build python plugin with custom python instalation

Tags: python, uwsgi

I want to build  python_plugin for uwsgi from my custom python installation under directory /opt/python36.
How can I set the path to that python during build time?
I run command bellow, but the plugin is assembled with Python 2.7 that is shipped with OS Cent 7.

```
PYTHON=python3.6; /usr/sbin/uwsgi  --build-plugin 
"/usr/src/uwsgi/2.0.15/plugins/python/ python36"
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am currently running into the same issue on an ubuntu 14.04 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `cd` into desired directory:

```
cd /opt/python36 && uwsgi --build-plugin "/usr/src/uwsgi/plugins/python python36"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the full path to your python binary in the `PYTHON` environment variable:

```
$ PYTHON=/opt/python36/bin/python3.6 /usr/sbin/uwsgi --build-plugin 
"/usr/src/uwsgi/2.0.15/plugins/python/ python36"
```

Comment: Add 

mv python36_plugin.so /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins

Answer (score 0):

I used a dirty solution. I temporary replaced shipped python with custom one, compile uwsgi plugin and then set back shipped python.

```
rm -f /usr/bin/python; ln -s  /opt/python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python;  # set correct python

PYTHON=python3.6; /usr/sbin/uwsgi  --build-plugin "/usr/src/uwsgi/2.0.15/plugins/python/ python36" # commpile uwsgi plugin

strings  python36_plugin.so|grep '3.6' # test python version

chmod 644 ./python36_plugin.so ; mv ./python36_plugin.so  /usr/lib64/uwsgi/;

rm -f /usr/bin/python; ln -s  /usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python # --> set back shipped python
```