# how to make uWsgi using python3.11

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi

I recently installed Python 3.11 on ubuntu 20.04

As I am running a web-service with python & flask through uWsgi, I'd like to move everything to the new version of python.

I had reinstalled and updated a punch of packages, and get the application running fine through a direct call to python3.11 and listening on the port 80.

Now I wanted to make the web service to use Python 3.11, but uWsgi still running the older version of python 3.8.

I removed and reinstalled uWsgi, but it didn't moved to the newly installed Python 3.11.

I couldn't figure out how to make uWsgi use a different python version. I tried to generate a new plugin as indicated in some old posts:

```
export PYTHON=python3.11
uwsgi --build-plugin "/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python python311"
```

it indicates "The distutils package is deprecated"

Any idea how to make uWsgi use the last Python version?

Comment: could you resolve this issue? @Rapace-bleu

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @mr.bug 
That was one year before.
I concluded that we need a new build of uwsgi.
Actually, I am not working on this subject.. I do not know if someone did it.

Comment: this solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233079/6195406